# Symfony: Doctrine - checking there's a connection

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Is there a simple way to debug why Doctrine is not connecting to MySQL?

`config.yml` has:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
```

and `parameters.yml` seems to have the correct connection information in it. E.g.

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: <my database name>
    database_user: <my database user>
    database_password: <my database password>
```

However this piece of code still echoes out "Not connected".

```
    $cnx = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
    if ($cnx->isConnected()){
        echo "Connected";
    }
    else {
        echo "Not connected";
    }
```

and I'm not getting any errors returned.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Symfony is doing lazy connection which means it will not connect to db until you (application) ask for it. If you didn't ask for it, you are not connected to db.

Comment: If you want force connection at specific point, just call `$cnx->connect()`

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getConnection()->connect();
$connected = $em->getConnection()->isConnected();
```

$connected will be `true` to indicate it is connected.

The [connect()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Driver.PDOMySql.Driver.html) establishes the connection, and then [isConnected()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Connection.html) returns a boolean to tell if it is connected.