# php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force not working

Tags: doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I get this error :
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 115:

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

In PDOConnection.php line 47:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

In PDOConnection.php line 43:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

In PDOConnection.php line 43:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away


doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250453/how-to-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away Can you connect to your mysql server?

Comment: how can i know if i am connected or not to mysql server ? i'm kinda of new to all of this btw

Comment: Checking your connection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224833/symfony-doctrine-checking-theres-a-connection?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

check your connection parameters in parameters.yml

database_port: port
database_name: table
database_user: root
database_password:******